# Proving the rate of change of angular momentum about CM is equal to total external torque about CM

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

I've been going through Taylor's Classical Mechanics book and I have to use the result:

$$\sum m_{\alpha} \bf{r}_{\alpha}' = 0$$

where $\bf{r}_{\alpha}' = \bf{r}_{\alpha} - \bf{R}$, $\bf{r}_{\alpha}$ is the position vector from an origin, and $\bf{R}$ is the position vector of the centre of mass relative to that origin, to prove that the time derivative of the total angular momentum about the centre of mass of a system is equal to the total external torque about the centre of mass.

I tried this idea:

$$
\bf{L}_{CM} = \sum_{\alpha} \bf{r'}_{\alpha} \times \bf{p'}_{\alpha}\\
 = \sum_{\alpha} \bf{r'}_{\alpha} \times m_{\alpha}\bf{\dot{r}'}_{\alpha}\\
\Rightarrow \bf{\dot{L}}_{CM} = \underbrace{\sum_{\alpha} \bf{\dot{r}'}_{\alpha} \times m_{\alpha}\bf{\dot{r}'}_{\alpha}}_{0} + \sum_{\alpha} \bf{r'}_{\alpha} \times m_{\alpha} \bf{\ddot{r}'}_{\alpha}\\
\Rightarrow \bf{\dot{L}}_{CM} = \sum_{\alpha} \bf{r'}_{\alpha} \times m_{\alpha} \bf{\ddot{r}'}_{\alpha}
$$
I can see that this would give $\bf{\dot{L}}_{CM} = \sum_{\alpha} \bf{r'}_{\alpha} \times \bf{F}^{ext}_{\alpha} = \Gamma^{ext}_{CM}$ where $\bf{\Gamma}^{ext}_{CM}$ is the total external torque about the CM.

My issue is that I haven't used the result at the top to prove this, and I actually thought that I could move the mass term:

$$
\bf{\dot{L}}_{CM} = \sum_{\alpha} \underbrace{m_{\alpha}\bf{r'}_{\alpha}}_{0?} \times  \bf{\ddot{r}'}_{\alpha}
$$
but wouldn't that just make the total external torque $0$ in all cases?

I may very well be missing something obvious but any help is appreciated!

Comment: PS. when writing math using `\bf{x}` is buggy and it spills the boldness outside the `{}`. Use `\mathbf{x}` instead, or use `{\bf x}`. See how `x \bf{y} z` renders: $x \bf{y} z$. Now look at `x \mathbf{y} z` renders: $x \mathbf{y} z$ or `x {\bf y} z` renders: $x {\bf y} z$.

Comment: Yeah I noticed this with the mass term when I was writing it but I haven't used Latex in a few years so I'm quite rusty. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your answer and insight, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the only allowed motion is rotation (about the center of mass) which makes

$$ \mathbf{\dot r}_{\alpha}' = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}_{\alpha}' $$

and

$$ \mathbf{\ddot r}_{\alpha}' = \boldsymbol{\dot \omega} \times \mathbf{r}_{\alpha}' + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}_{\alpha}') $$

Now to look at angular momentum

$$ \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{L}_{\bf CM} & = \sum_{\alpha} \mathbf{r'}_{\alpha} \times (m_\alpha \mathbf{\dot r}'_{\alpha} ) \\
& = \sum_\alpha m_\alpha \mathbf{r}'_\alpha \times (\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \bf{r}_{\alpha}') \\
& = \mathbf{I}_{\bf CM} \boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{aligned}$$

and its derivative

$$ \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{\dot L}_{CM} & = \underbrace{ \sum_{\alpha} \mathbf{\dot r'}_{\alpha} \times (m_\alpha \mathbf{\dot r}'_{\alpha} )}_0 + \sum_{\alpha} \mathbf{r'}_{\alpha} \times (m_\alpha \mathbf{\ddot r}'_{\alpha} ) \\
& = \sum_{\alpha} m_\alpha \mathbf{r'}_{\alpha} \times ( \boldsymbol{\dot \omega} \times \mathbf{r}_{\alpha}' + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}_{\alpha}') ) \\
 & = \mathbf{I}_{\bf CM} \boldsymbol{\dot \omega} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{I}_{\bf CM} \boldsymbol{\omega} 
\end{aligned}$$

So where is $\sum_\alpha m_\alpha \mathbf{r}_\alpha' = 0$ used? This *is the definition of the center of mass* and it is used to derive *linear* momentum as the product $$\mathbf{p} = (\sum_\alpha m_\alpha) \mathbf{\dot R} $$ from the sum of the individual momenta.

So why can't we use the origin to derive the rotational equations of motion?

We could certainly state that $$\mathbf{L}_0 = \sum_\alpha  \mathbf{r}_\alpha \times m_\alpha \mathbf{\dot r}_\alpha = \mathbf{I}_{\bf 0} \boldsymbol{\omega}$$

But taking the derivative and equating to the torques about the origin *only* works because the origin is an inertial frame. Do the above about an arbitrary point **A** that is moving at a constant velocity not parallel to $\mathbf{\dot R}$ and there is a term $\mathbf{\dot r}_A \times \mathbf{\dot R}$ that does not cancel out and the derivative angular momentum does not equal the sum of torques about this point.

Answer (score 0):

Up until
$$
\dot{\bf L}_{\rm CM} = \sum_{\alpha} {\bf r}'_{\alpha} \times m_{\alpha} \ddot{\bf r}'_{\alpha}
$$
your reasoning is sound. However, at this point in the text you say you think that
$m_{\alpha} \bf{\ddot{r}'}_{\alpha}$ is equal to ${\bf F}^{\rm ext}_\alpha$, but this
is not true in general, because each part of the body also experiences internal forces
within the body:
$$
m_{\alpha}\ddot{\bf r}'_{\alpha} = {\bf F}^{\rm ext}_\alpha + {\bf F}^{\rm int}_\alpha.
$$
Here ${\bf F}^{\rm int}_\alpha$ is the net force on part $\alpha$ owing to all the other parts of the body. You could write it, for example, as
$$
{\bf F}^{\rm int}_\alpha = \sum_{k \neq \alpha} {\bf f}_{k\alpha}
$$
where ${\bf f}_{k\alpha}$ is the force exerted on part $\alpha$ by part $k$.

So you need to allow for these internal forces, and then you will find that the relation to CM does come in after all. One brings in Newton's third law to say that
$$
{\bf f}_{k\alpha} = - {\bf f}_{\alpha k}.
$$

I won't write all the next steps here because
it is a good exercise to carry this calculation through. I hope you will try it.